# Which event can I use to catch in-page searches?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Is there an event that fires every time the user uses the browser search to look for a term in the page? How can I detect it and do something when that happens?

Comment: Possible duplicate of:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793864/listen-for-events-from-browser-find-window-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following for CTRL+F event, look at: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?68120-Handle-Ctrl-F-event-in-IE-Safari-and-Google-Chrome

```
  Ext.EventManager.on(document, Ext.isOpera ? 'keypress' : 'keydown', function(e){
      if(e.keyCode == 70 && e.ctrlKey){
        e.stopEvent();
        if(Ext.isIE){
        e.browserEvent.keyCode = 0;
       }
    // do stuff
       }
    return false;
    });
```

Comment: What if a user uses the quick search (just start typing)? Firefox has that feature, I don't know for other browsers.

Comment: Besides what Nikola said, there are plenty other issues with this approach: 1. Ctrl+F isn't always the shortcut. On Mac, it’s Cmd+F 2. It won’t catch subsequent searches, where it’s just hitting Enter 3. It won’t catch searches triggered via the mouse (through the browser menu)