# Chrome "Find" Breaks Scroller

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, dom

I created a custom horizontal scroller to page/slide through figures and legends.  Everything works fine until you use the "Find" function in Chrome.  If a keyword is located in a legend that is not currently in view, Chrome slides the parent DOM element to bring the hightlighted keyword into view.  When it does this, all my scroll controls are thrown off because, while the elements position is updated, the HTML does not reflect the offset.

Has anyone ever encountered this issue?

Normal Position:

[image]

Chrome Offset Breakage

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Two options I can think of.

1. Try to disable the find feature (See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793864/listen-for-events-from-browser-find-window-in-javascript)).
2. Modify the javascript and listen for scroll. Whenever that happens, run a correction.

If you post a demo, we may be able to do more.